# picklist value showing error variable doesnot exist

Tags: soql

```
string query = 'SELECT  Status, Origin, Priority from Case WHERE Status !=: Closed';
```

status picklist value have Closed value i want to fetch case whose status not equals to closed but its given error that variable name doesnt exits and closed is a value not a variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to reference a variable, `closed` that doesn't exist.

You could either declare a variable and set it with a value, then reference it using the query you've written:

```
String closed = 'Closed';
String query = 'SELECT  Status, Origin, Priority FROM Case WHERE Status != :closed;
```

Or you can just inject the value directly into the query:

```
String query = 'SELECT  Status, Origin, Priority FROM Case WHERE Status != \'Closed\'';
```

Answer (score 2):

`Closed` is not a variable, its a value, therefore it has to be used within quotes.

You can try this --

```
string query = 'SELECT  Status, Origin, Priority from Case WHERE Status != \'Closed\'';
```